# Repeating a task and Logging data in android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android programming. I have created an app in which if scan button is clicked,it displays the list of access points. I want to repeat the scan for every 10 seconds and log the data displayed on screen into a .csv file in sdcard/internal memory for further use. How can i do it? Could you please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
                try {
                    PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                    // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                    performBackgroundTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000); //execute in every 50000 ms
```

}